# Error while intergrating mixpannel with react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, package, mixpanel

```
mixpanel-react-native: MixpanelReactNative is null. 
Please follow the guide on the Github repository: https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-react-native.
Evaluating mixpanel-react-native.js
Evaluating custom-files/analytics.js
Evaluating screens/LogInScreen.js
Evaluating AppNavigator.js
Evaluating App.js
Loading App.js
```

I am using drafbit for react native app developement and i intergreted mix pannel using custome code but getting this error on loading app. I am also tried same method in expo app too and getting same error which means this error is associated with mixpanel package. anyone knows how to solve this issues ?

How to resolve this issue ?